# snowflake convert scientic notation to decimal output

Tags: sql, type-conversion, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Hi Does anyone know how to handle the scientific notation in snowflake?

So I got a column, VALUE with **FLOAT** dataType and I got the value like 9.6e-05 and 0.0234

I would like to **replace the decimal point dot with comma and then concatenate with other column** as my final result

When I convert it with hard code value  individually, it works fine, but when I use column name there it pops out the "too many arguments for function" issue

```
select 'Value:'||replace(to_varchar(9.6e-05,'999.999999'),'.',',') as Result
```

**Output** Value:0,000096

```
select 'Value:'||replace(to_varchar(0.0234,'999.999999'),'.',',') as Result
```

**Output** Value:0,0234

```
select 'Value:'||replace(to_varchar(VALUE,'999.999999'),'.',',') as Result From src
```

**Output** "too many arguments for function" error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure how to reproduce your error, because the problem as described, seems to work:

```
select value
    ,to_varchar(value,'999.999999') as tvc
    ,'Value:'||replace(to_varchar(VALUE,'999.999999'),'.',',') as Result
from values 
    (0.0234::float),
    (9.6e-05::float)
    as t(value);
```

[image]

So I am going to guess that value is a variant data type, because that is a reserved word that comes from the FLATTEN collection of table functions thus something like:

```
select *
from table(flatten(input=>parse_json('[0.0234, 9.6e-05]'))) as t;
```

[image]

and sure enough,

```
select *
     ,to_varchar(value,'999.999999') as tvc
from table(flatten(input=>parse_json('[0.0234, 9.6e-05]'))) as t;
```

[image]

> Error: too many arguments for function [TO_VARCHAR(T.VALUE, '999.999999')] expected 1, got 2 (line 10)

so if we first cast the variant to float:

```
select value
     ,to_varchar(value::float,'999.999999') as tvc
from table(flatten(input=>parse_json('[0.0234, 9.6e-05]'))) as t;
```

[image]

but if we add a non float data like `"not float"`

```
select value
     ,to_varchar(value::float,'999.999999') as tvc
from table(flatten(input=>parse_json('[0.0234, 9.6e-05, "not float"]'))) as t;
```

we get:

> Failed to cast variant value "not float" to REAL

so we need to use the TRY_TO_DOUBLE function to handle the failure, but:

```
select value
     ,to_varchar(try_to_double(value),'999.999999') as tvc
from table(flatten(input=>parse_json('[0.0234, 9.6e-05, "not float"]'))) as t;
```

> Function TRY_CAST cannot be used with arguments of types VARIANT and FLOAT

so we need to cast the variant data to TEXT so it can be handled by TRY_TO_DOUBLE, and gracefully produce nulls on text values.

```
select value
     ,to_varchar(try_to_double(value::text),'999.999999') as tvc
from table(flatten(input=>parse_json('[0.0234, 9.6e-05, "not float"]'))) as t;
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response  !! It does work. But I am still confused that 
 when you said variant data type, you mean this column's data type is VARCHAR? and can you use simple word to explain the keyword, FLATTEN collection  you mentioned here? I still don't get it why I get that error message. Thanks !!

Comment: if you have JSON or XML or ARRAY data, the type of the values retrieved via ARRAY_SPLIT or FLATTEN are of type `VARIANT` which just means looks like text, but not text, so they have to be cast to actual TEXT type, so the TO_DOUBLE can parse them. It is a little convoluted, but is this way for historical reasons, and Snowflake always seem to have more important things develop.